# c# Debug.Message gets called in console even its not true

Tags: c#

What i am trying to do is if the number int i==24 than i want to show a message  but message shows in debug even i is not == 24

> `Here is my code`

```
 for(int i = 0; i<25; i++)
    {
        SpawnPlatform();
        if(i == 24)
    {
        Debug.Log("Congratuations starting");
    }

    }
```

I also tried this code

```
int i = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<25; i++)
    {
        SpawnPlatform();
     

    }
       if(i == 24)
    {
        Debug.Log("Congratuations starting");
    }
```

it was showing this error

> A local or parameter named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope
> because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a
> local or parameter [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0136)

All i want to show a message when i == 24.
i tried my best to find solution but i failed,
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For your example, you loop through 25 times, with the final i value being 24 and it will print your message. The second is invalid syntax. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The first example works as expected. The second one is not compilable. So what do you see when you run the code from first example?

Comment: Do you mean you see that message 25 times? Your first example should work

Comment: If you also display the value of `i` within your loop, you will be able to see when & why it's showing the message

Comment: Yes the first is working as expected but my logic was wrong what actually i am trying to do is when a user reach to the platform number 24 i want an message to show them. but i think i need to apply diffrent logic